# Dynamic function calling in Java 8 Streams with Predicate Object

Tags: java, java-8

Here is my parent class

```
class Parent
{
String attrib1;
String attrib2;
String attrib3;

// getters and setters of three fields
```

Then I created a list

```
List<Parent> objList = new ArrayList<Parent>();
```

Then I added a number of Parent objects to objList.

Now I want to filter these objects based on value of the fields in the class. But I will get field name only dynamically.
I want to use streams for this purpose.

```
List<Parent> temp = objList.stream()
                .filter(nestedDo -> nestedDo.getAttrib2() == "manu")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here getAttrib2() varies. It can be getAttrib1() or getAttrib3().

So I need dynamic function calling. Can we achieve it using Predicates. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about the Predicate object. Please explain your answer elaborately with all concepts inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can create different [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) and use them based on condition.

```
Predicate<Parent>  first= e -> e.getAttrib1().equals("nanu"); 
Predicate<Parent>  second= e -> e.getAttrib2().equals(".."); 

List<Parent> temp = objList.stream()
            .filter(first)   // Similarly you can call second
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Reflection or Predicate will be a better apprach here?

Comment: A combination of reflection and predicate is needed in this case. You need to write the logic to choose the exact method 'name' and call is via reflection within the predicate expression

Comment: @Abhishek: Can you explain how to use reflection here in detail. I tried a lot to resolve using reflection, but I can't get a way to solve it.